# Click action firing on all elements EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a list with subelements that I hide. By clicking on a top element, it adds a class called active. For some reason when I click on one `<li>` it adds the 'active' class to all the other `<li>'s`

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |genre|}}
    <li {{action 'toggleActive'}} class="{{if isActive "active"}}">
        {{genre.title}}
      <ul>
        {{#each genre.subgenre as |subgenre|}}
          <li>{{subgenre.title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isActive:false,
  actions:{
    toggleActive(){
      this.toggleProperty('isActive');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `isActive` is single property used for all `li` elements. that's the reason for this behaviour. For your case you need to introduce `isActive` property for every `genre`.

```
<li {{action 'toggleActive' genre}} class="{{if genre.isActive "active"}}">
```

and in component toggle particular instance `isActive` proeprty and set it to `genre`,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    toggleActive(genre){
      Ember.set(genre,'isActive', !Ember.get(genre,'isActive'));      
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: if its normal object then try `!Ember.get(genre,'isActive')`

Comment: While its all great having the class add and remove, is it possible to stop clicking the inner `<li>` from firing the action?

Comment: You can try `{{action 'toggleActive' genre bubbles=false}}`

Comment: Sorry try this `preventDefault=false` ..if its not working let me know I will inform how to stop inside action method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133661/discussion-between-george-l-and-kumkanillam).